# How can I programmatically limit the execution of a Play 2.4 module to a single host?

Tags: scala, redis, playframework-2.0, aws-opsworks

Just to give some background, I have a Play 2.4 application which uses Scala 2.11.8. 

I deploy it to an AWS stack using OpsWorks which has *2 available instances*. In the application have a module which uses an ActorSystem scheduler to periodically execute a method to do some cleanup operation. When running one instance of the app locally the cleanup works fine, but once the app is deployed the cleanup is unnecessarily run on every instance. 
My question is not specific to the stack I am using, but rather a high-level approach to ***programmatically*** limit an operation to a single instance once the app is deployed. For the purpose of this question, assume I do not have access to the stack configuration.

I've searched for similar questions on S.O. but can't seem to find this particular issue. I also don't want to hardcode hostnames because that isn't a reliable solution.

Comment: Can you set up a master / slave kind of an architecture? I mean you could check the Elastic Load Balancer to keep one instance always active and the other as a standby?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the option of changing the stack settings because of the implications to the rest of the application. The goal was to try to accomplish this programmatically rather than with a config change. I guess I should have clarified that in the question.

Comment: Can you make the cleanup work by sending a HTTP request? This way, you can ensure that the request lands only in one instance of the server

Comment: The module that is doing the cleanup is part of the application which is running on the server. I don't want to hardcode any hostnames to ensure it only runs on one instance. The application should be able to execute the cleanup only once just by knowing its own hostname - even if there are _n_ number of other instances running in the collection.

Comment: Are you running in Heroku? I had the same issue and solved it using Redis to sync between actors when I wanted only one of them to execute a job. I can share the code if you like. just trying to understand if we had the same use case.

Comment: Someone has been systematically going through my profile and downvoting all questions and answers I've provided on Stackoverflow. The admins seem to be content letting it happen as well. Therefore, I would ask that any subsequent visitors of this post please vote genuinely and leave a comment explaining why you did or did not find the post useful. I'm not trying to indulge in some pathetic tit-for-tat, I just want to help the next person. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion that you could possible do:

1. Containerise your application using Docker
2. Use an orchestrator like Kubernetes or Docker Swarm
3. Set up service discovery for your application server (Your play application in this case)
4. Set up a Load Balancer that fronts your application server
5. By sending a HTTP request to your server (your Load Balancer), it is guaranteed that the request lands in just one instance of your application server which will then perform the needed clean up job.